# Visitor redirection based on country in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I need to redirect visitor based on its location, and show popup window before the direction.

Is there package available, and links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should  check out the IP2Location module?

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/ip2location-integration

I haven't tried it, but it looks to provide the functionality you require

Comment: Thanks. I know that. There seems to only that one. I haven't tried it either. Because its screenshot is so simple.

Comment: maybe you should try it, and then decide whether it works for you or not...? Your question was "is there a package". There is - I pointed you to it.

Comment: Thanks. I will mark the answer if the package meets my requirements. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Maxmind's GeoIP plugin for Apache - it's probably the most reliable source.

If you want to 'block' countries, there's also a piece of software called BlockScript.

EDIT: Just noticed you're on a Windows server. Still check out Maxmind though - there are a bunch of tools that will still be relevant to you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I know the company, which provides database of IP address to Country, and more. Ideally, it can also provide function that includes popup windows and asp.net dll in addition to the database.